# Optimal energy saving light bulb technology for a frequent switching on/off application?

Tags: led, power

Currently in the search for the most optimal energy saving light bulb technology for a frequent switching on/off application considering the lifespan and initial cost of purchase.

Answer (score 2):

> most optimal energy saving light bulb technology for a frequent
>   switching on/off application considering the lifespan and initial cost
>   of purchase

LED, LED, LED, LED every time